# How to set size of hover boarder around angular material textbox?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, textbox, hover

I'd like the border of the text box to be 1px when someone hovers and then change to 3px when clicked into.
By default the normal state (unfilled/not hover)of the text box border is 1px:

[image]

But the hover is 3px (when it should only be 3px after being clicked into):

[image]

Here is how it should be shown:

[image]

whenever I set the boarder size to 1px, the boarder doesn't switch to 3px when clicked into.

.form-pristine {
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
color: mat.get-color-from-palette($alt1, 800);
border-width: 1px;
}
}

How to I set the hover state border to 1px while keeping the activated(clicked into) state at 3px?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field .mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-flex {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you. This does add a 1px hover but it is going around the text box (and leaves a gap) instead of replacing the 3px black border that makes up the text box